# angularfire2 update object

Tags: javascript

I trying to update an object in firebase, I have an object that looks like this;

```
{
  '9': true,
  '10': true,
  '11': true,
  '12': true,
  '13': true,
  '14': true,
  '15': false,
  '16': true,
  '17': true,
  '18': false,
  '19': true,
}
```

I'm creating a button for each key/value pair,
and my goal is to toggle the boolean value on click.

these are my functions.

```
 toggle(event, day) {
  const dayPath =  `${this.basePath}/${day}`;
  if (event.$value) {
      this.block(event, dayPath);
    } else {
    this.open(event, dayPath);
  }

}

 block(event, day): void {
   this.db.object(day)
.update({  '9' : false });
}

open(event, day) {
  this.db.object(day)
   .update({  '9' : true });

}
```

I'm able to toggle as of now, however, I can't figure out how to make the '9' dynamic, based on the button clicked, any variable I use the becomes a key in the database.

Comment: `let key = '9'; this.db.object(day).update({ [key]: true });`

Comment: Brilliant!!!!!! thats what I needed, is there a way to make the boolean dynamic as well, !![value]? or something like that? either way thanks, man, right answer!!!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  block(event, day): void {
   this.db.object('firebase path') //give firebase object path for Example `${this.basedPath}/${day}` 
   .set(false);
  }
```